# Setting a pattern or symbol as NA value in geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-tile, ggpattern

I have data i want to visualise using *geom_tile*. The data deal with references in text data from either Germany or Spain to other European countries.

Example data:

```
data<- tribble(
  ~Ref_country, ~Country, ~Share,
  "ENG", "DE", 0.27,
  "ENG", "ES", 0.24,
  "ESP", "DE", 0.21,
  "ESP", "ES", NA,
  "GER", "DE", NA,
  "GER", "ES", 0.13,
  "FRA", "DE", 0.11,
  "FRA", "ES", 0.18,
  "ITA", "DE", 0.1,
  "ITA", "ES", 0.17,
  "POR", "DE", 0.03,
  "POR", "ES", 0.07,
  "RUS", "DE", 0.02,
  "RUS", "ES", 0.02,
  "NLD", "DE", 0.04,
  "NLD", "ES", 0.01,
  "BEL", "DE", 0.02,
  "BEL", "ES", 0.03,
  "SWE", "DE", 0.01,
  "SWE", "ES", 0.01
)
```

Since i do not count references from a country to itself, GER-DE and ESP-ES are NA.

I plot this with *ggplot*, *geom_tile* and *scale_fill_distiller*:

```
x %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = Ref_country, y = Country, fill = Share)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", linewidth = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_distiller(
    type = "seq",
    direction = 1,
    palette = "Greys",
    na.value = "white"
  )
```

resulting in the following [image: plot]

My question is: **is there a way to distinguish the NAs not by color, but by pattern?** Maybe through a creative application of *ggpattern*. Or alternatively, is it possible to add text ("NA") or a shape on top of the respective NA tiles? Since I will likely publish it in black and white, color is not a good distinguishing property.

Thanks in advance.

PS: As another alternative, can the color scale be restricted to greys that are clearly distinguishible from white?

Comment: An additional idea I had, but not sure how to implement: Is there a way to put a patterned layer of tiles below the plot, and set NAs to transparent? That would come close to my desired solution. Thanks to anyone taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, the first option which came to my mind would be to use a `"transparent"` color for the missings. Additionally I switched to `guide_bins` for the legend. And of course could you also add a symbol for the missings using e.g. a `geom_text` layer or perhaps a `geom_point`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

data %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = Ref_country, y = Country, fill = Share)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", linewidth = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_distiller(
    type = "seq",
    direction = 1,
    palette = "Greys",
    na.value = "transparent",
    guide = guide_bins(axis = FALSE, keywidth = unit(1, "cm"))
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

```r
data %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = Ref_country, y = Country, fill = Share)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", linewidth = 0.1) +
  geom_text(data = ~ subset(.x, is.na(Share)), aes(label = "X")) +
  scale_fill_distiller(
    type = "seq",
    direction = 1,
    palette = "Greys",
    na.value = "transparent",
    guide = guide_bins(axis = FALSE, keywidth = unit(1, "cm"))
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: The second solution is great, as it allows me to clearly mark NAs independent of fill or background color! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using `ggpattern`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

data %>%
  mutate(alpha = ifelse(is.na(Share), 1, 0)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Ref_country, y=Country, fill=Share)) +
  ggpattern::geom_tile_pattern(aes(pattern_alpha=alpha, pattern_fill=Share, pattern_size=NA) + 
  scale_fill_distiller(
    type = "seq",
    direction = 1,
    palette = "Greys",
    na.value = "transparent",
    guide = guide_bins(axis = FALSE, keywidth = unit(1, "cm"))
  ) +
  ggpattern::scale_pattern_fill_distiller(
    type = "seq",
    direction = 1,
    palette = "Greys",
    na.value = "black",
    guide = guide_bins(axis = FALSE, keywidth = unit(1, "cm"))
  ) +
  labs(fill="Share", pattern_fill="Share", x="Ref_country", y="Country")
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

This should give something like (although this below is applied to a bar chart):

[image]